# Programmatically upgrading Lucene indexes through multiple major versions in Java

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, upgrade

I am writing a utility to upgrade Lucene indexes from 3.6.2 in Java. Lucene's IndexUpgrader only works with the last major version. Currently 6.6.0 is the latest. This means I have to upgrade indexes through sequential major versions (3 to 4, 4 to 5, and finally 5 to 6).

This involves running multiple versions of Lucene's IndexUpgrader. Unfortunately IndexUpgrader is packaged at the same location in the Lucene jar thoughout multiple versions:

```
Lucene v4.9.1 : org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader
Lucene v5.5.4 : org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader
Lucene v6.6.0 : org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader
```

...and so on. Future releases will probably follow this pattern.

My question is can I include 3 different versions of Lucene in my application and instantiate a specific version of IndexUpgrader without copying Lucene source code into my package structure? If so, how?

Comment: IndexUpgrader is designed to be run as a command line tool. Why not do it the easy way and write a shell script?

Comment: Great question! The solution would have needed to be platform independent, which I suppose could be achieved a few different ways. We ended up using Maven's shade feature to move Lucene 4 and 5 so they wouldn't interfere with Lucene 6. The upgrade then worked, but we lost the ability to search dates stored as numbers in our upgraded index. In the end we shaded Lucene 3 for use by this index and moved on.

Answer (score 3):

I have it on good authority (really smart developers on the Lucene project) that compatibility is not guaranteed when upgrading more than one major version.  That is, if you're starting with version 5.x.x, upgrade the index with a 6.x.x version, and then try to use that index in version 7, there's absolutely no guarantee that the index will work.

So even if you figure out how to finagle the classloading so you can have multiple versions of Lucene in your application and get this whole idea working, the resulting index may not work anyway.

Comment: Excellent feedback - Thanks for sharing!

Comment: this is an interesting feedback, in your example - what if the index is also upgraded to 7? will it work?

Comment: If you advance through more than one major version, compatibility is not guaranteed.

In newer releases, the Lucene version that first wrote a segment is recorded within the index data and even if the data is rewritten by a newer version, Lucene will still know what version did the initial creation.  I'm reasonably sure that what I described above as "maybe it won't work" has become an explicit "it definitely won't work" in newer versions.  I do not have any definitive proof to point you at for this.